# data.table recode in selected columns

Tags: r, data.table

So I'm struggling with data.table. How do I make v1 and v3 numeric?

```
dt = data.table(v1 = c('1','2','3'), v2 = c(1,2,3), v3 = c('1','2','3'))
dt[,c(1,3), with = F] = lapply(dt[,c(1,3), with = F], as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
dt <- data.table(v1 = c('1','2','3'), v2 = c(1,2,3), v3 = c('1','2','3'))
dt[,':='(v1=as.numeric(v1),v3=as.numeric(v3))]
sapply(dt,class)
```

Comment: Also, you should [peruse the getting started vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: You could also take advantage of using a vector of columns to process it all in one go like `vars <- c("v1","v3"); dt[, (vars) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=vars]`

Comment: MichaelChirico, how can I see the next data.table vignette after the one you link to?  thanks.

Comment: And how are you planning to work with more than two vectors? Are you going to write all of them manually?